# Everytime I fetch pdf file, my ArrayAdapter stacks

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I need help about how to refresh my ArrayAdapter whenever I click the button to fetch files. It keeps on stacking the new list without clearing the last. Please help, also don't mind my English.

**This is my Array adapter**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PdfHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
        holder = new PdfHolder();
        holder.textViewName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.textViewUrl = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewUrl);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder= (PdfHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    pdf = data.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(pdf.getName());
    holder.textViewUrl.setText(pdf.getUrl());
    return row;
}


class PdfHolder
{
    TextView textViewName,textViewUrl;
}
```

**This is my code where I fetch file from my live server**

```
private void getPdfs() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching pdfs from server...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PDF_FETCH_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText (Files.this,obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("pdfs");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Pdf pdf  = new Pdf();
                            String pdfName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                            String pdfUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                            pdf.setName(pdfName);
                            pdf.setUrl(pdfUrl);
                            pdfList.add(pdf);
                        }

                        pdfAdapter = new PdfAdapter(Files.this, R.layout.list_layout, pdfList);
                        listView.setAdapter(pdfAdapter);
                        pdfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    request.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Can you suggest what should I do? or a code snippet to add or change?

Comment: Are you downloading data across internet? if you do then maybe your problem is downloading data in main thread because of that your app freezes. Or how do you populate adapter? Problem is not in that part of code.

Comment: This code doesn't show the problem. How do you attach the adapter to a ListView ? how do you populate the adapter ?

Comment: @Yupi yes I'm getting files from my live server

Comment: @davidxxx I'm using an arraylist sir

Comment: Do you clear your pdfList (or create a new one) when fetching the new data? if it's a class variable, you are adding new objects to the old list with   pdfList.add(pdf);

Comment: @Ascorbin then what should I change on my code sir to achieve the answer to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding new `pdf`s to the same list every time you load new data.

To fix this, before

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
```

do

```
pdfList.clear()
```